# How to set multiple values as defaultValue using Springfox 2.7.0, 2.9.2

Tags: springfox

I have a request parameter that accepts an array of string/enums, however when I validate the docs with openapi-generator, it says that the default is not of type 'array'. Looking at the api-docs, I see it made the default value a string, rather than an array.
How do I annotate the Springfox swagger so that I can list multiple values as the default selection?

```
@GetMapping
public PagedResults<PortfolioDto> getVisiblePortfolios(
        @ApiParam("List of Visibility")
        @RequestParam(defaultValue = "COMPANY,GLOBAL")  List<PublicVisibility> visibility) { }
```

produces

```
      {    
        "name": "visibility",
        "in": "query",
        "description": "List of Visibility",
        "required": false,
        "type": "array",
        "items": {
          "type": "string",
          "enum": [
            "COMPANY",
            "GLOBAL"
          ]
        },
        "collectionFormat": "multi",
        "default": "[COMPANY,GLOBAL]",
        "enum": [
          "COMPANY",
          "GLOBAL"
        ]
      }
```

and the error

```
     -attribute paths.'/api/discover/portfolio'(get).[visibility].default is not of type `array`
```